# Let $K$ be a normal subgroup of $H$ having a unique fixed point $y$ on $X$. Prove that $h(y) = y$ $\forall h \in H$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $H$ be a group of permutations of the set $X$. Let $K$ be a normal subgroup of $H$ having a unique fixed point $y$ on $X$

$\{y\}= \{x \in X: k(x) = x \forall k \in K\}$.

Prove then that $h(y) = y$  $\forall h \in H$.

I'm having some difficulty with this problem. My thought was, since $K \lhd H$, we know that $hK =Kh$, $\forall h \in H$.

So then we have $hK = h(y), y = \{x \in X: k(x) = x \forall k \in K\}$

and $Kh = y(h), y = \{x \in X: k(x) = x \forall k \in K\}$

So we have that $h(y) = y(h)$. Some how $y(h) = y$ and it would complete the proof.

I don't think this is right because of how I defined $hK$ and $Kh$. Any help to finish this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

It is easier to prove the following general statement: Let the group $H$ act on a set, and $K$ a normal subgroup.  Let $Y\subset X$ be the set of all poins of $X$ that are fixed by $K$.

Then $Y$ is a union of $H$-orbits. That is  for any $K$-fixed point $y$ and $h\in H$  one  has $h.y$ is also a fixed point for $K$.
(Your problem is the special case where $Y$ is a singleton set).

Calculate $k.(h.y)$. By definition of action this is $(kh).y$, and by normality this is $(hk').y$ for some $k'\in K$, and this is $h.(k'.y)$ which is $h.y$ (as $y$ is fixed by $K$. SO we see that $h.y$ is fixed by all $k$.

Comment: What I don't understand: If $S$ is the stabilizer group of $y$ then (assuming $H$  acts transitively on $X$) $X$ can be identified with $H/S$, the set of right cosets of $S$ in H (with the right multiplication as action). It is known that the stabilizers of other elements of $X$ are conjugates of $S$. Now saying  $K$ fixes $y$ is equivalent to say that $K \subseteq S$ so if K is normal then  K lies in all the conjugates of $S$, so $K$ fixes all the points of $X$.